# How do you pronounce ROC?

Tags: model-selection

In regards to ROC curves, how do you pronounce ROC? I have always spelled out the letters like R-O-C but I sat through a sales demo today where they guy pronounced it as a word like "rock" as in "the rock curve".

So who's right?

Answer (score 4):

I have personally only heard the letters being spelled out:

> "Here we see the R-O-C curve on this pronunciation model is far from optimal"

Answer (score 2):

In a German statistics course I attended the professor always called it "rock curve".
I don't think there's a real right or wrong here but personally I just default to the quicker pronunciation ("R-O-C" -> "rock", "S-Q-L" -> "sequel").